# Dash Core wallet won't synchronize. Says "Not connected" at top

Tags: dash, ios

I get this error when I open my Dash wallet and the 'syncing' stays at 0%. How do I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My router firewall security settings were set to 'High'. 'Medium' fixed the problem.